# SendMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND) failed when mouse captured

Tags: winapi

I'm using the win32sdk, but some messages would never work as expected while mouse was captured by calling SetCapture(), such as:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    SetCapture(hWnd);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
    ReleaseCapture();
    return 0;
```

The Window won't be maximized. but why?
Additional,
1. if I use `PostMessage()` instead, it works.
2. if I use `PostMessage()` instead and remove the `ReleaseCapture();` statement, it doesn't work again.

Comment: 1 - PostMessage is asynchronous and you call ReleaseCapture() before WM_SYSCOMMAND is processed. So you have only one question: Why you can't maximize if mouse is captured?

Comment: By the way, if you want to maximize window before capture just call SendMessage before.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

PostMessage is asynchronous and you call ReleaseCapture() before WM_SYSCOMMAND is processed. So you have only one question: Why you can't maximize if mouse is captured?

I haven't found any info on this but read here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx

"When the mouse is captured, menu hotkeys and other keyboard accelerators do not work." I suppose WM_SYSCOMMAND is not processed also because of this restriction. May be it was done like this to keep coords consistent.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's reason.
I'm completing a DirectUI library. When button down, I call SetCapture(). For reason sometimes the window loses capture not because of the button up message, so I notify the UI to change its capture-state when receive the WM_CAPTURECHANGED message. 
The question is what time I call the ReleaseCapture() function when button up?
1. before the UI proc.
    Since the UI's capture-state has changed , it does nothing in response to button up message.
2. after the UI proc.
    Yeah, it's the question that I asked above.

Maybe I should take another logic about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As norekhov said menu hotkeys don't work when the mouse is captured. When the mouse is captured the the only action a user can take that will result in the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message being sent is to use a system menu hotkey.

Note that the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message is only meant to be used to notify a window of a user initiated action. When you send it to a window, you're in essence trying to mimic a user's action. In this case you don't need to do this. You can tell the window to maximize itself directly:

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

In this case it won't appear to be a user command, so it won't be ignored because the mouse has been captured.

Comment: I call SetCapture() and redirect the message to the event handler, it try to maximize the Window like that and get failed. :)

now I know I should prefer using ShowWindow.